# Backbone.js: Promise is returned before Parse has been hit in Fetch call

Tags: backbone.js, promise

Any idea how to make sure that the Collection has ran the response through the Parse function before returning the Promise in a Fetch call?
ie.

```
var colsComplete = _.invoke(cols, 'fetch'); // cols is an array of collections
$.when(colsComplete).then(callback); // this runs before the Parse function has been hit!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.invoke(cols, 'fetch')` returns an array of promises and you pass it to [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) which reacts to a single argument as this

> If a single argument is passed to `jQuery.when` and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any `doneCallbacks` attached will be executed immediately.

What you probably want to do is to [apply your array as a list of arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$.when.apply(null, colsComplete).then(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
_.each(cols, function(collection){
    collection.fetch({
        success: callback
    });
});
```

It's a little longer but it should work.

Comment: this will call the `callback()` after each success, right? I need to call it once they're ALL done.